# When to use require and when to provide dependencies through arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, coding-style

I've been wondering what is the preferred way of injecting dependencies in node.js code.

I've been working on a project where there is no dependency injection. This is why i have 2 ways of providing dependencies in my code:

Through constructor/function arguments - this has the disadvantage of exploding the number of arguments in functions as i pass arguments from higher levels of my program to the lower ones,

```
function createListener(queue) {
    return function listen() {
        while (true) {
            const messages = queue.receiveMessages();
            ...
        }
    };
}
```

Using require() - this is equivalent to hardcoding those dependencies making if harder to mock and test.

```
const queue = require('./queue');

function createListener() {
    return function listen() {
        while (true) {
            const messages = queue.receiveMessages();
            ...
        }
    };
}
```

I've been trying to hit a sweet spot between those. When providing a dependency which is a complex mechanism i tend to inject it, when dealing with values or less crucial mechanisms i use require.

Is that ok? What would be a better approach?

Comment: Another factor, apart from the complexity of the dependency: do you actually *need* to inject different dependencies?

Comment: What do You mean? From the top of my head i can see two types of those dependencies: code that has some logic or a value. Regardless of which one it is i should be able to substitute them while testing. Also i think it is good for readability if the dependencies are explicit.